# Tracking eMails in Outlook 2007

Tags: c#, email, outlook, vsto

Greetings Overflowers,

I am trying to develop a VSTO/C# corporate email tracker for specially signed emails.
I am relying on:

1. Inspectors.NewInspector
2. Inspector.Close
3. Inspector.Activate
4. Inspector.Deactivate

Somehow, the Inspector events stop firing after sometime.
I register 2, 3 and 4 in the body of 1 after checking for the sign.
I tried to keep track of already registered inspectors but no hope.
Any clue ?

**UPDATE:** Here is a sample code. The evens OnSelect and OnOpen fires few times and then stops suddenly:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook;
// using Microsoft.Office.Core;

namespace eMailTrackingSystem
{
    public enum TrackingEvent
    {
        Opened, Closed, Forwarded, Deleted
    }

    public partial class eMTSAddIn
    {
        private ArrayList trackedEmails = new ArrayList();

        private void InternalStartup()
        {
            this.Application.ActiveExplorer().SelectionChange += new ExplorerEvents_10_SelectionChangeEventHandler(OnSelect);
        }

        private void OnSelect()
        {
            Selection selection = this.Application.ActiveExplorer().Selection;

            foreach (object item in selection)
            {
                if (item is MailItem)
                {
                    MailItem email = (MailItem)item;

                    if (email.Subject == "eMTS" && !trackedEmails.Contains(email.EntryID))
                    {
                        email.Open += new ItemEvents_10_OpenEventHandler(OnOpen);

                        trackedEmails.Add(email.EntryID);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void OnOpen(ref bool cancel)
        {
        }

        private void OnClose()
        {
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using Inspector Wrappers?  They are essential for properly dealing with every item that is opened by a user:

Developing an Inspector Wrapper for Outlook 2010: 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff973716.aspx

A similar approach can be used for monitoring the items a user has selected in the Explorer.